# Source games: missing russian texts in XUbuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, steam

I've recently came from LInux MInt 18.3 to XUbuntu 18.04 and installed garry's mod and other source games via steam. When I launch it, some russian texts disappear. There is no problems in garry's mod menu, only while playing, but even in main menu in portal 2.
[image: no russian text at all in garry's mod]
[image: nice portal 2 menu]

Output (garry's mod) (too big to paste directly): https://pastebin.com/29e7XSQQ

I use `nvidia-drivers-396` drivers with `cinnamon`. Same problem appear both in fullscreen and windowed modes.

There wasn't any problems on my old mint 18.3. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you should contact Steam support too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to steam support and forums, solution is here:

Add follwing to ~/.fonts.conf (create if doesn't exist):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  …
  <!-- fix source games cyrillics -->
  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="family" qual="any" >
      <string>Helvetica</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
      <string>Nimbus Sans L</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  …
</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not testing this, but there is no risk to try the following process.

Enable russian caracters encoding

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Tick the one named ru_RU.UTF-8. Finally restart your computer to ensure the new locale is available in all tty and try again your game.

Comment: `ru_RU.UTF-8` is already checked.